# Maven surefire running tests in a module in parallel

Tags: maven-3, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a multimodule maven project, `Z` (let's say Z is having modules `A`, `B` & `C`). Is it possible to run all the tests in `A` in parallel when I do `mvn test`. But the tests in `B` and `C` should run sequentially?